# Android: equal sized layout with two scrollable views

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I need a layout with a fixed area, that contains

- a spinner,
- a checkbox and
- two buttons (which should be aligned horizontal)

and a variable area (depending on the size of the device) that contains

- a listview and
- a textview.

The two views in the variable area should share the rest of the screen, in a way that both get equal vertical space.

What do I do wrong?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/mainSpinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mainCheckbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox1"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainButton1"
                android:text="@string/mainButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onReadDBClick"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainButton2"
                android:text="@string/mainButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onCreateDBClick"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mainListView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        </ScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="2000"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

P.S.: After I tried several changes (the ones, that I understand...) I played arround a bit, as I didn't really find anything suitable in two hours... hope, that I did not mess up too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first. You should not put scrollview inside scrollview. 
Also ListView should not be inside scrollview. 
Read about RecyclerView and how to use it instead of ListView.

Something like this?:)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/mainSpinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/mainCheckbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox1"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onReadDBClick"
                android:text="@string/mainButton1"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onCreateDBClick"
                android:text="@string/mainButton2"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainListView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2000"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the textview mainTextView1 does not scroll... can you help me, to find out, why?

Comment: Try to put mainTextView1 in ScrollView.

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="2000"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                />
        </ScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mainSpinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mainCheckbox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/checkbox1"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/mainButton1"
                    android:text="@string/mainButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="onReadDBClick"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/mainButton2"
                    android:text="@string/mainButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="onCreateDBClick"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mainListView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />
        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2000"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```